# Reg ex 24 for 24hour time only allow 4 digits

Tags: regex

I need to use regexp for time (24 hour) and only 4 digits should be valid. Ex 0730 is valid and 730 isn't.

I've tried with: `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]`

But this doesnt work as i want. Anyone sees anything wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the question mark:

```
([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])[0-5][0-9]
     ^ This one
```

The `?` means "the previous match is optional."  Removing it makes it mandatory.